# Error getting results from buffer. Simba JDBC BigQuery driver

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, logstash

I'm executing a Logstash pipeline that queries BigQuery through Simba JDBC Driver:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        id => "categories-input"
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_driver_library => "..."
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "..."
        statement => "
            SELECT categoryid, categoryname, filters
            FROM dataset.categories
            WHERE categoryid = 12345;"
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        id => "categories-mapping"
        rename => {
            "categoryid" => "[category][id]"
            "categoryname" => "[category][name]"
        }
        remove_field => ["@timestamp", "@version"]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        template => "/usr/share/logstash/shared/generic.json"
        template_name => "generic"
        id => "categories-updating"
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        index => "categories"
        document_id => "%{[category][id]}"
    }
}
```

Also, my whole `dataset.categories` table is really small, less than 100 megabytes

However my `filters` string is quite long (10,796,031 characters to be precise) and as a result I'm getting the following exception:

I also get the very same exception even if I don't transform filters to a string.

> Exception when executing JDBC query
>   {:exception=>#BigQueryJDBCDriver Error getting results from
>   buffer.>}

That's my connection string if it helps:

```
jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=VerySeriousProject;OAuthType=0;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=veryimportantemail@VerySeriousProject.iam.gserviceaccount.com;OAuthPvtKeyPath=/usr/share/logstash/drivers/key.json;Timeout=600;AllowLargeResults=1;
```

What would I have to change in order not to receive these kind of exceptions and be able to query data?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: Well, that's the whole stacktrace I have @MarkRotteveel

Comment: That isn't a stacktrace though, that is just an exception message.

Comment: That's literally all I have. This query runs as Logstash JDBC input and produces just this error message. If I had more - I'd put it here.

Comment: Can you enable bignumber support, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql >supportBigNumbers: When dealing with big numbers (BIGINT and DECIMAL columns) in the database, you should enable this option (Default: false). Also for troubleshooting can you do a select without filters and another select when you substring XXX chars from filters to verify this is indeed the problem

Comment: @TamirKlein I'm not really sure what you're suggesting with MySQL npm package. This is about BigQuery. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Yes sorry mysql has a parameter to indicate big umber support the link was just to show you the options. Ignore the npm, can you set the bignumber paramter and check again

Comment: I don't think that's the case @TamirKlein as I couldn't find where to set this option in BQ

Comment: Not in BQ in your SImba JDBC driver

Comment: @TamirKlein None of these options seem to be what you're mentioning. Do I look at the right place? https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/allowlargeresults.htm

Comment: Sorry I feel you will have to contact the author of Simba JDBC